# Solr index multiple tables from MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, solr, multiple-tables

I have following mysql tables

```
 1. user(user_id,email) 
 2. tweets(tweet_id,user_id,tweet) 
 3. tags(tag_id,tag)
 4. tweets_tags(tweet_id,tag_id)
```

I want to show current user's tweets under "My Tweets" Tab in application. I want to get following data from Solr

```
user_id
email
tweet where user_id=x
tags where tweet_id=xx
```

How to index those mysql table on Solr? I only what to know the code of **`schema.xml`** and **`data-config.xml`** for **`Full/Delta import`**.

> Note : I am not asking about MySQL connector etc, I have done already.

Answer (score 1):

The use case you've described doesn't seem to justify using solr. You would just make sure you have proper keys and indexes and do it in mysql directly.

If for some reason you MUST use solr, you could probably prepare all the data and feed it to solr in a tag/tweet/user structure like this

- user1 - tweet1 - tag1
- user1 - tweet1 - tag2
- user1 - tweet2 - tag1

and so on.

Then from solr you query by user, and then sort and group by tweet and then tag.
However I must state again that the solution I just described is implemented much safer with a higher confidence on the result by using plain sql.

Should you provide more details on your desired outcome, I'd be happy to suggest the database structure along with the necessary foreign keys and indexes and the queries you need to get your data out.

Comment: Agree with this answer. I had a similar requirement for a SOLR POC and The way I did was I denormalized the data and fed that query to DataImportHandler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DIH (dataimporterhandler), I guess that link should be the solution for you:
[Import with sub entities](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example)
If you have problem with writing the exact configurations, please let me know, I can assist you.

Comment: i have read that page already, what i need to know is some of queries are so complex that we need to handle them with php array, run one query, get result and then run another query using data from result. how to index data like that, using multiple entities or multiple cores.

Comment: I suggest sub entities. Assuming that you will want to show results from all your tables (solr core joins queries are slow, very slow) For speed up the import you can create Materialized views and also use sub enties at import time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369226/what-is-the-difference-between-a-join-query-and-embedded-entities-in-solr-dih/13374509#13374509